# Deleting substrings in a panda dataframe using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, substring

Hi I want to delete `{endIndex:8,startIndex:0,value:` from `date-and-time:{city:{endIndex:8,startIndex:0,value:Atlantic}` in multiple rows and columns in my dataframe.

Here's an example of one row in my dataframe.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ad13551df70d8025b7811db"), "Article url" : "http://wreg.com/2015/08/02/mpd-officer-killed-in-the-line-of-duty-identified/",  "Full text" : "Blah blah", "Json" : "{circumstances:{number-of-shots-fired:{endIndex:-1,startIndex:-1,value:},type-of-gun:{endIndex:-1,startIndex:-1,value:}},date-and-time:{city:{endIndex:7,startIndex:0,value:MEMPHIS},clock-time:{endIndex:226,startIndex:218,value:9:15 p.m}, victim-section:[{age:{endIndex:151,startIndex:148,value:33,},gender:Male,name:{endIndex:146,startIndex:135,value:Sean Bolton},race:{endIndex:-1,startIndex:-1,value:},victim-was:[killed]}]}", "Publication date" : "2015-08-03 10:24:27+00:00" }
```

As you can see `{endIndex:,startIndex:,value:}` shows up in a bunch of different columns with different values (sometimes no value). 
So how do I go from

```
date-and-time:{city:{endIndex:7,startIndex:0,value:MEMPHIS}
```

To my desired output

```
date-and-time:{city:MEMPHIS}
```

*I know the value doesn't make sense so please ignore that.

So far I was thinking of using pandas.DataFrame.replace combined with regular expression to find substrings that match my conditions.

`new_df=old_df.replace('abc{endIndex:X,startIndex:Y,value:ABC', '', regex=True)`

What would be the equivalent regular expression for abc, ABC, and X, Y? Where they can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

hope it helps. :)

```
new_df=a.replace('{endIndex:(.+),startIndex:(.+),value:', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Can you answer me, why did you downvoted my answer. It is worked fine for me.